# How to sort multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multidimensional-array

How can I sort a multidimensional array or an object array in node.js?Is there any inbuilt method to do this? If not then how can i do it?

I need to sort the output array in following code by name.

```
request(urls, function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var output = JSON.parse(body);          
    output.sort(function(a,b){
        if (a.name > b.name)
          return 1;
        if (a.name < b.name)
          return -1;
        return 0;
     });                
    console.log(output);            
  }           
});
```

*

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort

Comment: _multidimensional array_ is not very precise. How many dimensions does it have? Can you provide a sample of your array?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But I have already tried array.prototype.sort(), but was not working for node.js

Comment: it is a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Please provide example input and expected [console] output.